# Integrating Laravel Passport with Socialite to consume from Android/iOS app

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-5.4, laravel-socialite

i want to add Laravel Socialite to let user to login to my Android app, now i'm using Passport for auth (Passwpord Grant Token) so i want to login users and return the token so the app could make the rest of the api calls.

How could I achieve this? I've searched but unlucky atm.

Don't know what to add to the Callback function to return the a regular Passport response, something like this:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer", // or other method
    "expires_in": 31536000,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV....WaYC14FGOPuhViVIE",
    "refresh_token": "XhZKHr2S2Ikp...wMKWfmksñT/MxVQvg="
}
```

Comment: The token is returned from `/oauth/token`, you can store that. What type of grant are you using?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy to my regular flow (without socialite) i'm using Passport Grant Token. But to receive this you need user/password. How could I access or what method to use to login the user using id/email?